# *ngFor behaviourSubject | async don't update

Tags: angular, behaviorsubject

I have a problem with BehaviorSubject and async pipe. It don't show me all the items of BehaviorSubject after .next(). It show me just 'prova' item. I logged errors$ in the interceptor and I have other items.Why it don't show me all the items in the page? Thanks

**template**

```
<div class="alerts">
    <div class="alert" *ngFor="let error of (errorInterceptor.errors$ | async) ">
        {{error}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**error-Interceptor**

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })

export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

errors$ = new BehaviorSubject<string[]>(['prova']);

    constructor() {} 

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
            if (err.status >= 400 && err.status < 500) {

                console.error('error-interceptor:error status=' + err.status + ' message=' + err.message + ' msg='+err.msg);
                const errors = [...this.errors$.value];
                errors.push(err.status);
                this.errors$.next(errors);
                console.table(this.errors$.value);

            } else {

                console.error('error-interceptor:err=' + err.error + ' statusText=' + err.statusText + ' status:' + err.status);

            }

            const error = err.error.msg || err.statusText;
            return throwError(error);

        }));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right, because the value is what you pass to `.next`.
if you want to collect all errors the you need to change your code to something like

```js
errors$.next([...errors$.value, newError]);
```

a possible solution is to create a token and to share the `BehaviourSubject`.

```js
providers: [
  {
    provide: 'errors',
    useValue: new BehaviorSubject(['prova']),
  },
],
```

then in your component code instead of injection of the `ErrorInterceptor` inject `@Inject('errors') public readonly errors$: Observable<string[]>`.

and update the Interceptor to do the same.

```js
constructor(@Inject('errors') protected readonly errors$: BehaviorSubject<string[]>) {} 
// ....
this.errors$.next(errors);
```

after that in the template your can use

```
<div class="alerts">
    <div class="alert" *ngFor="let error of (errors$ | async) ">
        {{error}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in the code above I see that errors are in `errors`, but not in `errors$`. to put them into `errors$` you need to call `errors$.next(errors);`. For example before `this.errors.next(errors$);`

Comment: then please update the code sample in description, because currently it confuses.

Comment: thanks, how do you provide `errorInterceptor` to the template?

Comment: I inject it in the component s constructor. It works, I see the item I passed in the behaviorsubject declaration

Comment: I've updated the answer. The solution is to move the error subject to be an independent dependency.

Comment: Thanks I try after lunch

Comment: it works with your suggestion but what's happen with my code?

Comment: I think with your original code the instance you get as a dependency in the template and an instance which HTTPModules uses are 2 different instances, maybe you would need to play with multi=false, or something, but I would say the way with a separate dependency to collect error is the right approach because of single responsibility of every class.

Comment: I declared @injectable root. It seems like it lost connection with the subject...